How do i fix this optimization compiling issue on hardhat?
My hardhat.config.js compiler is not compiling my contracts correctly, i set optimization true with 200 runs, yet after compiles it says false and that i must enable optimization.
I tried everything, clean cache, forced recompile, nothing worked
